# How can I limit has_many to certain scopes in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, has-many, belongs-to

I am setting up a situation where I only want certain scopes of my model to "has_many" of another model.  As a hypothetical situation, imagine I have a model called `Tree` and a model called `Apple`.  I only want tall trees to be allowed to have apples, so I scoped my tree model into `tall`.  How can I use a has_many appropriately in this situation?

I am using Rails 4.

**Sample Code**

**Tree.rb**

```
scope :tall, where(:tall => true)
scope :short, where(:short => true)
has_many :apples (need to alter this line to only have this happen for :scope tall)
```

**Apple.rb**

```
belongs_to :tall, class_name: 'Tree'
```

I am unsure if the rest of the code is the right way either, so please let me know if there are any improvements I can make to it.

Answer (score 2):

The gem 'pundit' makes it easy to create and allow model specific and oo procedures. May be what you are looking for.

https://github.com/elabs/pundit

Comment: thanks, but I think that might be a little bit more than what i need.  I was hoping to accomplish this in one or two quick lines of code

Comment: Ok. Well for future reference, I would check out Pundit, for it can be very useful in almost any application. Good luck.